# Expanding height of parent div based on children's height

Tags: css

I know there are several similar questions answered here, but I can not seem to get this working.

I have two parent `div`s - one is like a frame with a border and padding, the second is a solid black background, and the third is where a transparent image will actually be placed. I need the two parent `div`s to expand their height based on the image's height.

I have this working for the `div` with the black background, but I can't get the parent `div` with the border to expand it's size:

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vpdj4kst/

```css
#builder_container {
  width: 100%;
  /*overflow: auto;*/
  position: relative;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
}
#builder_contents {
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.builder_img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="builder_container">
  <div id="builder_contents">
    <img class="builder_img" src="image.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have set the image to `position: absolute;` which will take it out of the flow causing the parent elements to act as if it wasn't there.

> Elements that are positioned relatively are still considered to be in
>   the normal flow of elements in the document. In contrast, an element
>   that is positioned absolutely is taken out of the flow and thus takes
>   up no space when placing other elements.

Position (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Remove `position: absolute;` from `.builder_img` and the parent containers will react to its height.

```css
#builder_container {
  width: 100%;
  /*overflow: auto;*/
  position: relative;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  clear: both;
}
#builder_contents {
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.builder_img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="builder_container">
  <div id="builder_contents">
    <img class="builder_img" src="http://coolspotters.com/files/photos/1036167/adidas-st-girls-straw-hat-profile.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```